# creating portfolio descriptions with max number of words

Tags: javascript

I am showing off projects on a website and each image has a description. I want to cut off the description with an ellipses after 50 or so characters. I also don't want the last word to be be partially cut off.

Example:

decription: "this building was designed in 1970 on the corner of 11th and 15th street."

description on website: "this building was designed in 1970..."

The javascript is external and the descriptions are under the class name "card-text". This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var string = document.getElementByClassName('card-text');
function truncate(string){
 if (string.length > 20)
  return string.substring(0,20)+'...';
 else
  return string;
};
```

Comment: Where is your  function call.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva I'm new to js, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Change the `maxLength` variable for different maximum lengths.

```js
function truncate(str) {
    var maxLength = 50;
    
    if (str.length <= maxLength) {
        return str;
    }
    
    var truncated = str.slice(0, maxLength - 3);
    var lastSpaceIndex = truncated.lastIndexOf(' ');
    
    if (lastSpaceIndex === -1) {
        return truncated + '...';
    }

    return truncated.slice(0, lastSpaceIndex) + '...';
}

var str =  "this building was designed in 1970 on the corner of 11th and 15th street.";

console.log(truncate(str));
```